# how vc++ debugger show pointer like array?

Tags: visual-c++

when i have a var like `char my_array[23]` I can see it all the array value by click on name and expanding the array.

but I can do it when var is like `char *my_data` I see only first data.

how debugger in vc++ can have same behavior for this two case?

Comment: You don't know how many elements the pointer points to.  The debugger doesn't know either.  The only safe answer is "one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must write in watch window

my_data,23

and can expand it like a array.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are different types, in the first case (`char[23]`) debugger knows how many elements are in array, the second case (`char*`) is just a pointer to `char` and debugger shows only the first element of the array